# panel exit in java

Tags: java, swing, frame, exit

```
Frame fr;
...
fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(Frame.???)
```

What should I write instead of "???" to close the frame?

Answer (score 6):

I think you meant to use `JFrame`:

```
JFrame fr;
...
fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And with a (old) AWT Frame, you'd do something like this to close it:

```
final Frame frame = new Frame("Frame test");
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        frame.dispose();
    }
});
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @user713744, I guessed so because you mentioned `setDefaultCloseOperation`, which an AWT Frame doesn't have.

Comment: That 'swing' tag added to the question just cranks up the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

There is code example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    JFrame frame;

    public Test() {
        JButton button = new JButton("exit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();        
    }
}
```

Comment: No, a `java.awt.Frame` does not have a `setDefaultCloseOperation` method.

Comment: @user713744, to close frame use dispose method - frame.dispose();